# Error when installing Blender 2.78

Tags: windows, installation, error

over the past few days, I have been trying to install "Blender 2.78" on Windows OS on 64-bit. The error is, I have insufficient permissions to download the software. Here is a picture:

[image]

Other information: I am logged in to the OWNER of the computer, or "ADMIN" of the computer. This is the only used account on my desktop computer.

Comment: I would explore that folder, and check why the user 'Amber', with role 'Administrator', cannot access it (permissions).

Comment: The fact that you use account which has Admin privileges which is the only one doesn't mean you have admin privilileges when running executables on Windows (and I suggest having 2 accounts one of which is actually admin). There is at least one more role configured by default which doesn't have privileges. Anyway this question is about permisions configuring on Windows and not Blender itself

Comment: Yeah like Dr Sybren said just use the zipped portable setup, much cleaner solution. Or if you insist rightclick on the installer and choose *Run as administrator*

Comment: Note that this is not an issue with blender but how you configure your OS, only administrative accounts will be able to install and uninstall software or alter the operating system.

Answer (score 3):

You don't have to install Blender. Just [download](http://download.blender.org/release/) and extract the ZIP file and you can run it directly. There is no need for administrator privileges.

Comment: Yeah but now I can't open any .blend files :/

Comment: What does that mean? Can't you run Blender? From Blender, can't you choose File, Open? Or something else?

Comment: imho @BlueJEF means that  using zip archives ( I always do that) .blend files are not configured to open automatically (double click) with the zip version - hint: in this case you have to manually associate .blend files to your desired blender.exe after extracting the zip archive.

Answer (score 1):

The problem occurs with the Blender MSI attempting to access the following locations, if you have previously moved your default user folders (such as Documents, Downloads, etc.) to another location.

This occurs even if you are a full Administrator on Windows 10.

The files the installer attempts to create in this location are:

- `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Installer\{E29A1273-2E7A-40E7-AA63-428A11D59429}\Production.ico`
- `C:\Users\[username]\Desktop\blender.lnk`
- Uninstall `Blender.lnk` (unsure of folder)

Modifying permissions of the `C:\Users\[username]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Installer` folder to add Full Permission to System will help, and allow you to progress and then skip the subsequent error messages.

I think the Blender installer may need tweaking to resolve.